# PDO count rows where username matches

Tags: php, oop, class, pdo, return

I am trying to match a username in the database. If the username match it returns true otherwise it returns false.

At the moment it will always return false even when the username is correct.

Here is the class and call I'm using:

```
class register{
  private $result;

  public function __construct($post_data, PDO $dbh){

    $this->post_data = array_map('trim', $post_data);
    $this->dbh = $dbh;

  }

  public function checkUsername(){
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("COUNT(*) FROM oopforum_users WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->post_data['reg_username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $this->result = $stmt->rowCount();
    if($this->result == 0){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
  }

}


$register = new register($_POST, $dbh);
if($register->checkUsername()){
    //continue
}else{
    echo 'ERROR: That username is taken, please choose another one.';
}
```

Why is it returning false even though the username's do match?

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($this->result);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `SELECT` statement:

```
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM oopforum_users WHERE username = ?");
```

Apart from that your query will always return a row (exactly 1 row), but the contents of that row could contain a 0 for the row count, so you need to change your logic: Either select a real column instead of `COUNT(*)` and use `$stmt->rowCount()` or read the value of the count and check for that.

Comment: @crm: For future reference, enable PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION to make PDO throw exceptions on errors. That will make it infinitely easier for you to spot errors right on.

Comment: Still struggling to grasp this..I have attempted `SELECT username` and `$stmt->fetchColumn` but this returns false.

Comment: @Truth Good idea, but will that work without a `try` - `catch` block?

Comment: @crm If you use `SELECT username FROM ...` you should stick with `$stmt->rowCount()`.

Comment: @jeroen: Without a try catch block, your program will blow up (fatal error), which will force you to see the error anyway. In your example, you simple wrap the try/catch block around the method call (not inside the method declaration itself).

Comment: @Truth aaaaaaaah, thanks, never used it without `try` - `catch`. Makes sense though.